# I get "Unknown service start result" error on multiple intents

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I'm trying to  invoke certain functions of my service with intents sent from my activity.

This is how I send intents from activity (in UI thread):

```
Intent it = new Intent(MyService.INTENT_ACTIVITY_POSITION_CHANGED);
it.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
it.putExtra("posPercentX", x);
it.putExtra("posPercentY", y);
startService(it);
```

This is how my **onStartCommand** looks like in MyService:

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
       super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

       if(intent.getAction().equals(INTENT_ACTIVITY_START)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"onStartCommand ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }else if(intent.getAction().equals(INTENT_ACTIVITY_POSITION_CHANGED)){
        // here comes some code to get extras from intent
        Log.d("INTENT_ACTIVITY_POSITION_CHANGED", "x=" + posX + " y=" + posY);
        //TODO preveri
       }
       return startId;
    }
```

after few calls I get:

```
ERROR/ActivityManager(52): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown service start result: 4
```

Why do I get this error? any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you think you should be returning `startId`? The documentation for onStartCommand() is

> **intent**    The Intent supplied to startService(Intent), as given. This
>   may be null if the service is being
>   restarted after its process has gone
>   away, and it had previously returned
>   anything except
>   START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY.
>
> **flags**     Additional data about this start request. Currently either 0,
>   START_FLAG_REDELIVERY, or
>   START_FLAG_RETRY.
>
> **startId**   A unique integer representing this specific request to
>   start. Use with stopSelfResult(int).
>   **Returns**
>
> ```
> * The return value indicates what semantics the system should use for
> ```
>
> the service's current started state.
>   It may be one of the constants
>   associated with the
>   START_CONTINUATION_MASK bits

So you need to return START_STICKY, or one of the values from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_CONTINUATION_MASK

Comment: Hehe thanks for quick answer. I'm still getting to know android and the wrong return value was not apparent to me.

Comment: No worries. I can come of sounding like a dick, but it's not personal =P